# Using regular expression in pyspark to replace part of the key inside a column containing maps?

Tags: python, pyspark, pyspark-schema

I am stuck on this problem.

I have a pyspark dataframe looks as below-

| id | year | data | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | {'living_costs[1]':'','living_costs[2]':'','living_costs[3]':'','living_costs[4]':''} | 2019-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |
| 2 | 2020 | {'living_costs[1]':'','living_costs[2]':'','living_costs[3]':'','living_costs[4]':''} | 2020-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |
| 3 | 2021 | {'living_costs[1]':'','living_costs[2]':'','living_costs[3]':'','living_costs[4]':''} | 2021-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |
| 4 | 2022 | {'living_costs[1]':'','living_costs[2]':'','living_costs[3]':'','living_costs[4]':''} | 2022-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |

My expected output is looks like replacing '[' and ']' with '_' and living cost with lc. Which looks as below-

| id | year | data | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | {'lc_1_':'','lc_2_':'','lc_3_':'','lc_4_':''} | 2019-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |
| 2 | 2020 | {'lc_1_':'','lc_2_':'','lc_3_':'','lc_4_':''} | 2020-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |
| 3 | 2021 | {'lc_1_':'','lc_2_':'','lc_3_':'','lc_4_':''} | 2021-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |
| 4 | 2022 | {'lc_1_':'','lc_2_':'','lc_3_':'','lc_4_':''} | 2022-09-04T02:32:00.990+0000 |

can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and since no one replied yet; I am posting my solution. I  used transform_keys. The code looks like-

```
df=df.withColumn('data',transform_keys(col('data'),lambda k,v:regexp_replace(k,'living_costs','lc')))\
     .withColumn('data',transform_keys(col('data'),lambda k,v:regexp_replace(k,'\[|\]','_')))
```

Thank you! I hope this helps someone.